# is it possible to use regex in js to replace several different chars?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all accented char in a string by it's unaccented version, for sorting.
I found how to match the accented ones, but is it possible to use a regex to replace each one?
I mean:

```
var re = /ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ/g;
var str = "ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ";
var newstr = str.replace(re, 'M');
console.log(newstr);
```

this prints 'M'
but I need :'uUuUaaaeeeiiiooouuuAAAEEEIIIOOOUUnN'

Is this possible?
thanks

Comment: what about `^` `âêîôûÂÊÎÔÛ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use character classes.

```
var re = /[ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ]/g;
```

Then, you can pass a function as a second argument to the `replace` function. This function shall contain the conversion logic. A simple way would be to use a conversion map.

E.g.

```
var re = /[ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ]/g;

//incomplete but you get the idea
var conversionMap = {
    'ù': 'u',
    'Ù': 'U',
    'ü': 'u',
    'Ü': 'U',
    'ä': 'a'
};

"ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ".replace(re, function (c) {
    return conversionMap[c] || c;
}); //uUuUaàáëèéïìíöòóuuúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓUÚñÑ
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PT6Xc/6/)

Comment: Thanks, that's part of it, now i get one 'm' for each char! Great! Now this 'logic' would be an other regex? I mean if i build this in javaScript with for()s if()s and switch()s there is no good to use regex in first place right? Sorry if I'm dumb about this.

Comment: Ahhh!! great now I get the idea.Thanks!

Comment: Well, i thougth i did, look http://jsfiddle.net/PT6Xc/2/ it's not working as expected.. Did i missed something?

Comment: @v.k. `replace` doesn't modify the original string, it returns a new one. Strings are immutable. http://jsfiddle.net/PT6Xc/3/

Comment: I new it was some stupid mistake. Thanks a lot @plalx. that did it. I'll finish the map and keep it in jsfiddle just in case.  thanks

Comment: @v.k. Obviously you should put that logic in a reusable function ;) You can also use a self-executing function to encapsulate the whole thing without having to recreate the map at each invocations.

Comment: I did the hash map and modified to a cached version http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/PT6Xc/7/

Comment: @Vitim.us, Have a look at mine in the link above your comment. You can actually cache the replace callback as well and you do not need the logical `||` operator anymore.

Comment: You guys are amazing! :) Learning a lot from all this.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/YPtaN/4

```
var deaccentuate = (function(){

    var accent = "ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ",
        latin  = "uUuUaaaeeeiiiooouuuAAAEEEIIIOOOUUnN".split("");

    var re = new RegExp("["+accent+"]", "g");

    return function(str){
        return str.replace(re, function(c){
            return latin[accent.indexOf(c)]; }
        );
    } 
})();

deaccentuate("Olá, como estás?"); //Ola, como estas?
```

### Benchmark

I realized a benchmark test with a 2KB text and my function was **faster** than other answers, reaching 59000 Ops/sec

http://jsperf.com/deaccentuate

[image]

Comment: Shorter, but quite inefficient.

Comment: @Vitim.us thanks, it works, but the other version is indeed faster.

Comment: @Vitim.us :) great! I didn't even know jsperf. Love it thanks for that also. The diff with @ plalx was minimal.

Comment: Yeah not much difference, but I just wanted to know if it was really "inefficient" as commented, seems to not be the case. Also have a small footprint than the replace object.

Comment: At the end of the day, you are all right, and have helped me a lot. All answers are correct, I can only mark one as correct though... But i can thanks you all...

Comment: @v.k. Do not forget that tests should be made in **multiple browsers**. I am not sure that you would get the same results. To me it makes no sense that `indexOf` would be faster than a simple property lookup, even if that property isin't numeric.

Comment: @plalx yeah I know indexOf will always be slower than a object, but maybe because the overhead/bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: @Vitim.us Could you add the method I used in my answer in your Benchmark comparison?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly verbose, in order to be readable. (Well, to each their own, anyway.)

```
var deaccentuate = (function() {
  var conversion =
      { 'a' : /[äàá]/g
      , 'e' : /[ëèé]/g
      , 'i' : /[ïìí]/g
      , 'o' : /[öòó]/g
      , 'u' : /[üùú]/g
      , 'n' : /ñ/g
      , 'A' : /[ÄÀÁ]/g
      , 'E' : /[ËÈÉ]/g
      , 'I' : /[ÏÌÍ]/g
      , 'O' : /[ÖÒÓ]/g
      , 'U' : /[ÜÙÚ]/g
      , 'N' : /Ñ/g
      }

  return function(str) {
    return Object.keys(conversion).reduce(function(str, c) {
      return str.replace(conversion[c], c)
    }, str)
  }
}())
```

Usage: (http://jsbin.com/UFEbuho/1/)

```
var input = "ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ"

console.log(deaccentuate(input))
```

The idea is to loop over the keys of the conversion table and replace anything that matches the pattern of that key to the key itself. This is certainly not the most efficient way to do this, but unless the input strings are fairly long it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: I liked this, thanks. Also it brought my attention to reduce(). You think this has performance differences with the above solution proposed by @plalx?

Comment: @v.k. The `reduce` part will not have much impact since looping over a few items is quite fast, however performing 12 replace operations will certainly have a negative impact. However, it will not be noticeable on small inputs, but you know, once the helper function is written, it's still one line to perform the replace operation independently of the implementation...

Comment: @plalx is absolutely right. The discussion re: performance really is moot since your input probably isn't large enough for it to make a difference and/or the implementation can change without changing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think about an easier way to efficiently remove **all** diacritics from a string than using this [amazing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/5061000).

See it in action:

```js
var str = "ùÙüÜäàáëèéïìíöòóüùúÄÀÁËÈÉÏÌÍÖÒÓÜÚñÑ";

var str_norm = str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
console.log(str_norm);
```